# PJSIP Media Error

Tags: c, audio, raspberry-pi, pjsip

I am working with Raspberry Pi's and PJSIP Softphone library, i have one Raspberry where everything works fine and one who always throws a error. The sound device is an usb headset which is configured correctly, means i can play sounds via `aplay path/to/file`.

I am just starting a call via a button:

```
if ( button[1] ) { 
    digitalWrite( GPIO_LED_CALL3_AKTIVE, HIGH );
    while ( GPIO_Read( GPIO_BTN_CALL3 ) );
    dest_uri = pj_str( "sip:6001@" SIP_DOMAIN );
    call_init = 1;
}   
/* Initiate Call if call_init was set */
if ( call_init ) { 
    call_init = 0;
    printf ( "\n=============   Call to %s   =============\n",dest_uri );
    int status = pjsua_call_make_call( acc_id, &dest_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    delay ( 1000 );
}
```

The error which is thrown looks like following

```
Expression 'SetApproximateSampleRate( pcm, hwParams, sr )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1294
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1870
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1994
Expression 'SetApproximateSampleRate( pcm, hwParams, sr )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1294
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1870
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/../../../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1994
```

I get a short audio output which stops after 1 or 2 seconds.

I have build PJSIP by source like following:

```
    sudo su

    apt−get install build−essential automake autoconf libtool \
       libasound2−dev libpulse−dev libssl−dev libsamplerate0−dev \
       libcommoncpp2−dev libccrtp−dev libzrtpcpp−dev libdbus−1−dev \
       libdbus−c++−dev libyaml−dev libpcre3-dev libgsm1−dev \ 
       libspeex−dev libspeexdsp−dev libcelt−dev
        cd /home/pi
        wget http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.4.5/pjproject−2.4.5.tar.bz2 
        tar xvjf pjproject −2.4.5.tar.bz2
        cd pjproject−2.4.5.tar.bz2
        ./configure && make dep && make
```

As far as i can say its now a programming error since the code works on one device. So is it an audio miss configuration oder  did i build pjsip wrong? Maybe i forget a package or sth?

if you need more information about the code i can give you more. Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

I have playback methods which looks like following:

```
static void ringback_start( pjsua_call_id call_id ) {
    print_Debug_Info( "*** Starting ringback to out_call ***\n" );
    pj_str_t fname = pj_str( "Sounds/Freizeichen3.wav" );
    pjsua_player_create( &fname, 0, &cm.player_id );
    pjsua_conf_connect( pjsua_player_get_conf_port( cm.player_id ), 0 );
}

static void ringback_stop( pjsua_call_id call_id ) {
    print_Debug_Info( "*** Stopping ringback to out_call ***\n" );
    pjsua_conf_disconnect( pjsua_player_get_conf_port( cm.player_id ), 0 );
    pjsua_player_destroy( cm.player_id );
}
```

I have some feeling that this could create the error since i get the error even before the call is established.

Comment: Check if the ./pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h file is same on both the environments.

Comment: If you use both for capturing and playback, it will give this error..This is bug. I am sure the pi in which it is working, you have used it only for playback and not for capturing while the other device is used for both

Comment: so i have looked into the config_site.h and it content was different on both system. So i adjusted everything and recompiled it but the error still appears.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar i have edited my post and maybe you may look at it. I am not sure it that is what you mean with playback. Well one side is just doing nothing accept for accepting calls, the other side waits for a button to be pressed and then calls a specific client. So now if i switch the purposes of the devices, the error appears.